# How to don't repeat the same fields for each proto structure?

Tags: go, data-structures, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm using for the first time protobuf .proto files.

I have many models which have the same fields:

```proto
message Player {
  uint64 id = 1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createdAt = 2;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp updatedAt = 3;
  string firstname = 4;
  string lastname = 5;
  //...
}
```

```proto
message Team {
  uint64 id = 1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createdAt = 2;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp updatedAt = 3;
  string name = 4;
  //...
}
```

```proto
message League {
  uint64 id = 1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createdAt = 2;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp updatedAt = 3;
  string name = 4;
  //...
}
```

... and many others...

As you can see I have **the same fields repeated in each structure**.

What is the best practice to DRY (don't repeat yourself) in this case?

I'm using Golang.

Can I embed them like in Go language?

Comment: You can create a message with  common fields, and use that. However, for these cases, it is usually more readable to repeat yourself.

Comment: Can you show how, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define a new message with the fields that are often repeated, and use that as field type in other messages:

```
message Metadata {
  uint64 id = 1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createdAt = 2;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp updatedAt = 3;
}

message League {
  Metadata metadata = 1;
  string name = 2;
  //...
}
```

In Go then you'll initialize the `Metadata` field as a normal struct (package selectors will depend on how you actually generate Go types from the protobuffers):

```
func newLeague() *grpcgen.League {
    return &grpcgen.League{
       Metadata: &grpcgen.Metadata{
           Id:        1000,
           CreatedAt: ptypes.TimestampProto(time.Now()),
           UpdatedAt: ptypes.TimestampProto(time.Now()),
       }
       Name: "foo",
       //...
    }
}
```

Edit:

> Do you think this slows down the coding/decoding process

We can run the following benchmark:

```
package foo

import (
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes"
    "foo/grpcgen"
    "testing"
)

var withmeta = &grpcgen.LeagueWithMeta{
    Metadata: &grpcgen.Metadata{
        Id: 1000,
        CreatedAt: ptypes.TimestampNow(),
        UpdatedAt: ptypes.TimestampNow(),
    },
    Name: "foo",
}

var nometa = &grpcgen.LeagueNoMeta{
    Id: 1000,
    CreatedAt: ptypes.TimestampNow(),
    UpdatedAt: ptypes.TimestampNow(),
    Name: "foo",
}

func BenchmarkEncProto(b *testing.B) {
    b.Run("encode with meta", func(b *testing.B) {
        b.ReportAllocs()
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            b, _ := proto.Marshal(withmeta)
            if b == nil {
                panic("not marshaled")
            }
        }
    })

    b.Run("encode without meta", func(b *testing.B) {
        b.ReportAllocs()
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            b, _ := proto.Marshal(nometa)
            if b == nil {
                panic("not marshaled")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

```
$ go test -bench=. ./proto_benchmark_test.go -benchtime=10s
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7660U CPU @ 2.50GHz
BenchmarkEncProto/encode_with_meta-4            13124650           948.8 ns/op        96 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkEncProto/encode_without_meta-4         25832161           417.0 ns/op        64 B/op          2 allocs/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  24.629s
```

**Not** wrapping the fields in the `Metadata` message has a better performance, which is not surprising. In practice, this is not going to affect your program in an appreciable way.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a message with common fields:

```
message Meta {
  uint64 id=1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createdAt = 2;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp updatedAt = 3;
}

message Player {
  Meta meta=1;
  string firstname = 4;
  string lastname = 5;
  //...
}

message Team {
  Meta id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  //...
}
message League {
  Meta meta=1;
  string name = 2;
  //...
}
```

Comment: Do you think this slows down the coding/decoding process? Specially using Go?

Comment: You can measure and see. It is not likely to be significant compared to network speeds.